# Set minimum wait time for AJAX callback action

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-callback

I have an app built in HTML that loads fullscreen inside a modal with $.get()

I have a loading screen that is triggered when someone clicks the icon to load the app.

I want the loading screen to appear for a minimum of 2 seconds before clearing out and showing the app.

Is there a good, safe way to start a timer that runs for 2000 milliseconds, checks a variable that is populated by the callback to see if it is null, and then proceeds with a certain action only when the variable is loaded?

I know a while loop will do the trick, but might cycle 1000 times before the content loads on a slow day, and this seems like an inefficient way to do things.

**Answer**

```
$('#testApp').click(function() {
    var twoSecMin = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function () { twoSecMin.resolve(); }, 2000);
    $('#appModal').fadeIn(400);
    $.when($.get("/usm/portal/_layouts/monkeysphere/test.aspx"),twoSecMin).then(function (data) {
        $('#appContainer').html(data[0]);
        $('#appContainer').show();
        $('#appModal').fadeOut(200);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using a recent version of jQuery (1.5 or later), you can create a [`$.Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and [`resolve`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/) it with a fixed timeout:

```
var twoSecMin = $.Deferred();
setTimeout(function () { twoSecMin.resolve(); }, 2000);
```

Also, save the `jqXHR` returned by `$.get`, which is an extended `Deferred` object:

```
var ajaxReq = $.get("/usm/test.aspx", ...);
```

Then [wait for both](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/):

```
$.when(twoSecMin, ajaxReq).then(function (_, res) {
    // ready...

    var data = res[0];
    // ...
});
```

Comment: This looks promising, let me try it out

Comment: It's stalling forever, which is likely my fault. Going to post my current code, and try to fix it.

Comment: @Wesley Ah. `ajaxReq` isn't for the `data` in the callback. You want to set it to the `jqXHR` (an extended `XMLHttpRequest`) object that performs the request. `var ajaxReq = $.get("/usm/portal/_layouts/monkeysphere/test.aspx");`.

Comment: Already marked this right, because it's MOSTLY working. Reposted my code above, and now I'm getting it to work, but I'm getting too much data back. If you don't want to answer here, I'll repost as it's technically a separate question.

Comment: Found it. Answer posted above

Answer (score 1):

You could probably just use a `setTimeout(fn, 2e3)` to do this.

For testing if your variable is null, you could use `yourVariable === null`.

Comment: Gotcha. The trick is, how to get it to check again without looping like crazy if x === false

Comment: @Wesley You probably want to re-architect your code to use a callback.

Comment: Check my code above from the edit, it might make the question clearer. I want to execute the callback IFF it has been more than 2000 milliseconds

Comment: @Wesley Can you just move the `setTimeout()` into the callback of your `$.get()`?

Comment: I could, but it's possible that the $.get itself (theoretically) will take 2000 milliseconds to execute, and I don't want to make user wait longer than necessary. Once the callback fires, I just want to wait the remainder of unused time from isReady